# Facebook Like Button won't Acknowledge Click after Login IE 10

Tags: facebook-like, internet-explorer-10

I'm running into an odd behavior with the Facebook Like button. Big surprise: it involves IE 10.

Repro Steps:

1. Using Internet Explorer 10 and without already being logged into Facebook, go to a page with Facebook Like button on it.
2. Click the like button, which should generate a pop-up to log in to your Facebook account.
3. Log in.
4. Pop-up window will close on it's own.

Notice that the Like button has not switched to the grey'd out version indicating you've successfully liked the page.  No matter how many times you click the button, it will not change.  Checking Facebook, you will notice there is no status indicating you've like this page.

1. Click IE 10's refresh button.
2. Once the page has reloaded, click the Like button.

Now, the button works.  Check this out:

1. Log out of Facebook and repeat steps 1-4.

Button still works!  But wait, there's more!

1. Close and reopen Internet Explorer 10 and repeat steps 1-4.

Broken again.

So, I'm stuck trying to figure out why this is happening.  Has anyone else run into this issue and do they know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open issue with Facebook. Please ref. below thread. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/138361736300782/